# How should I use commas in the middle of compound sentences?

Tags: commas, word-usage

How do you punctuate the following sentence?

> The introduction of a low cost Hartford Cycle line had staved off the competition for a number of years, but, by 1897, with 700 competitors in the market, the Colonel was in trouble.

What commas, if any, should be removed?

Where should commas be inserted in the following sentence?

> Several of the subsidiaries continued on in receivership for a number of years but by 1914 the last of his companies had finally been sold or dissolved.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localised. It merely asks how to punctuate a particular sentence and has no general applicability or interest for others. 

Answer (score 2):

> "The introduction of a low-cost Harford Cycle line had staved off the competition for a number of years, but by 1897, with 700 competitors in the market, the Colonel was in trouble."

(Remove the comma after *but*.)

> "Several of the subsidiaries continued . . . in receivership for a number of years, but by 1914 the last of his companies had finally been sold or dissolved."

(Insert a comma after *years*.  Also, I don't think the "on," which I elided, was necessary.)